# What is an example of a formal group law that does not come from an abelian variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, brauer-group, formal-groups

I am curious to find an example of a 1-d formal group law that does not come from a splitting of the formal group law of an abelian variety.

I am aware that we can craft logarithms from the formal Brauer group, but can formal group laws obtained in this way also be thought of as coming from integrating an invariant differential of an abelian variety?

Do formal group laws that come from formal Brauer groups of a variety lose the ability to be studied via the p-divisible group of the Jacobian of that variety?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t notice this. If you’re willing to look at non-algebraically-closed bases, then even $\mathbf G_{\text m}$, the multiplicative formal group, doesn’t show up in the formal group of an Abelian variety over $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: @Lubin forgive my slowness, but if we take $x^{p-1}-1$ (i.e, $x^{p-1}-z^{p-1}$, if we want it to be projective) do we not get a variety with 1 as the multiplicative identity?

Comment: Well, that’s a zero-dimensional groupscheme, not connected, and definitely not an Abelian variety.

Comment: There's also $\hat{\mathbb{G}_a}$ which can't come from any abelian variety since its of infinite height.